# algpseudocodex: Adding comment to \until" line

Tags: algorithms, algpseudocode

I'm using `algpseudocodex` to type-set my algorithms, and I'd like to have a comment on each line.

Minimum example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocodex}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\Repeat \Comment{Comment1}
    \State $x$ \Comment{Comment2}
\Until{$y$} \Comment{Comment3}
\State $z + x + y3$ \Comment{Comment4}

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

However, when compiled, Comment3 is incorrectly right-shifted. This does not seem to depend on the amount of text in the `Until` clause or in the `Comment` clause:

[image]

How can I fix this and right-align all the comments correctly? I get an error that `Overfull \hbox (15.00002pt too wide)` on the line in question.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue. Perhaps if you add a compilable code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`  ....

Comment: @SimonDispa I added documentclass and begin/end document (so it's now the full .tex code which gives the screenshot on my machine). I get the issue on both report and article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is referred to in [this issue on algpseudocode's Github](https://github.com/chrmatt/algpseudocodex/issues/6), from 5 Dec 2021.

I think that you are using a platform that doesn't have the latest version of the package installed (v1.0.1).

Are you using Overleaf? [Overleaf switched to using TeX Live 2021 in October 2021](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-2021-now-available) for its packages, so I'm guessing that they haven't updated to include the changes from the latest patch of TexLive 2021 (which I believe includes this patch).

Comment: Exactly right, thank you. You are clearly better than me at googling :)

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce the issue with TeX Live 2020, that's running `algpseudocodex` version 1.0, released 2020-08-16.

With TeX Live 2021 the version of `algpseudocodex` is 1.0.1, released 2021-12-05 (which is the current version), the issue disappears.

Comment: Thank you! This was the issue, feeling silly...

Answer (score 2):

With your same file I got the right result and no warnings.

[image: a]

I added the command     `\listfiles` at the beginning. Look at the end of the .log file to see all the files loaded and their versions.

See my own list at bellow.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocodex}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{algorithm}[h]
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            
            \Repeat \Comment{Comment1}
            \State $x$ \Comment{Comment2}
            \Until{$y$} \Comment{Comment3}
            \State $z + x + y3$ \Comment{Comment4}
            
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

.

```
*File List*
article.cls    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
algorithm.sty    2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating environment
float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
algpseudocodex.sty    2021-12-05 v1.0.1 pseudocode typesetting
kvoptions.sty    2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
algorithmicx.sty    2005/04/27 v1.2 Algorithmicx
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
fifo-stack.sty    2014/03/24 v1.0 Multi-FIFO/stack system
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
tabto.sty    2018/12/28  v 1.4  Another tabbing mechanism
tikz.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgf.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfrcs.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfrcs.code.tex
pgfcore.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
graphicx.sty    2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
pdftex.def    2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
pgfsys.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgffor.sty    2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
expl3.sty    2021-02-18 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdftex.def    2021-03-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
l3keys2e.sty    2021-03-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
xparse.sty    2021-01-09 L3 Experimental document command parser
xparse-2020-10-01.sty    
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
***********
```